# Looking for an electronic copy of U. Uhlhorn's old paper

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

Can an electronic copy of the following paper be found?

U. Uhlhorn, On the connection between transformations in classical mechanics and in quantum mechanics and the phase space representation of quantum mechanics, Arkiv för Fysik 11, 87-100 (1956).

Comment: [Somebody had it on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252377/42637) more than a year ago. The link there does not work anymore though, and the user who placed it also does not exist anymore. Maybe you could ask the user [Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic) (currently moderator) who requested it there.